# last 'li' elements in 'ul' are going down when browser is minimized

Tags: html, css, browser, html-lists, cross-browser

last 'li' elements in 'ul' are going down when the browser is minimized.

Comment: Any HTML markup is appreciated... or preferably a working example on jsfiddle

Comment: What do you mean by "going down"?

Comment: You should reproduce the bug in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), the CSS and HTML provided behaves as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/rbj9d/1/

Comment: @ My Head Hurts: Ya I agree with you . Just see the screen shot that I added above. The code I provided is a from sample webapplication. When I added the same code in my dev application (Sharepoint app) I am encountering that issue. Is there any properties needs to be added in css to avoid this kind of behavior? I am unable to figure out where exactly i am getting the issue

Comment: @Srikanth I'm afraid that there is not much that can be done to help if you cannot reproduce the bug, provide relative code or offer a live link. The only thing I can suggest is to [validate your markup](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: @ My Head Hurts: I updated the original code (HTML and CSS)in the above. HTML code is taken from IE developer tool. ignore javascript/jquery in it

Comment: You can't have divs inside a ul, it's not valid HTML.

Comment: @ Devlin: even though it is working fine r8.

Comment: @Srikanth The code you provided still works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/7hdnp/. Recreate the problem in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and then post it in your question

Comment: @ My Head Hurts: Really impressed with your support. I am unable to reproduce the issue, but still have issue in sharepoint application. but do you have any idea about these kind of issues. Which things cause these issues like that? anyways thanks a lot

Comment: @Srikanth sorry, not really. Invalid mark-up or CSS styles are the only things that spring to mind. Also, when writing a comment to someone, don't put any spaces in the name or after the @ sign. Otherwise the person you are writing to will not get the notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got solution for this. Main div was overriding 'search' section in the site. this search div pushing menu div li elements down. I removed the search div then everything is working fine. So much relieved now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is this helps out your problem, but the endtag of </ul> was wrong in your example. When this is not the answer, just show us your code from 'workportfolio' until the end. Maybe there is a little error in your code over there.